# Which function is asymptotically larger between n and log(n!)

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

I guess `O(log(n!))` is asymptotically slower than `O(n)`.
Am I right ?

Comment: Look up Stirling's formula, it answers this question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, your guess is completely wrong! try to expand `log(n!)` as the following:

```
log(n!) = log(n * (n-1) * ... * 1) > log(n * (n-1) * ... * n/2) > 
log((n/2)^n) = n log(n/2) \in Theta(n log(n))`
```

Therefore, `n \in O(log(n!))`

Comment: @CharanShetty Definitely, the growth of `n log n` is faster than `n`. Is it clear for you?

Comment: Yes, `n log n` will have faster growth than `n`